# Сборка приложений с возможностью линковки к "старой" glibc

Tags: gcc, g++, makefile, libc

Коротко о задаче: необходимо использовать бинарники, собранные из-под новой системы, на старой системе. Обе системы Gnu/Linux.

Проблем было несколько, но почти все они были решены. Хоть и не важно, какое именно приложение собирать, для примера укажу именно то, на котором я застрял. Сейчас дошло до сборки подходящих либ Qt5.6 (5.7 требует как минимум C++11, что вызывает дополнительные проблемы).

После сборки, я переношу эти либы вместе с исполняемым файлом и указываю LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Как бы я не пытался собрать эти либы, лучшее, чего я добился, это сокращение количества ошибок до четырёх (однотипных, поэтому указываю одну строку):

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_x.y' not found (required by ./libQt5Core.so.5)
```

На версию ругается только libQt5Core.so.5. При этом максимальная требуемая версия = 2.9.

На новой системе установлена версия glibc 2.24, на старой - 2.3.6.

Прошу помощи по решению этой проблемы!

Comment: Пользуйтесь `#ifdef` наверняка есть тесты на версию qt

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за ответ! А можно подробнее? Вопрос не в версии Qt, а в сборке программ/библиотек с возможностью линковки к старой libc.so.6. Здесь Qt привёл в качестве примера.

Comment: @nick_n_a Не могу уловить Вашу мысль. Вот я получил версию библиотеки 2.3.3, но при запуске приложения линкер просит как минимум 2.9. Что именно нужно указать в define, чтобы линкер этого не делал?

Comment: Я был уверен что у вас ошибка компиляции. Вам нужно как-то через #define задать что libc вам надо 2.3 (это не даст вам использовать функции более новой libc), кроме того link-ку нужно дать указание что б он собрал не для 2.9 а для 2.3. Сделайте слепок lib-файл именно с вашей старой библиотеки (tlibimp утилита), и подключите именно его в проэкт. Скорее всего так. А когда вы запускаете исполнимый модуль - то уже среда говорит что модуль вам не подходит.

Comment: Незнаю поможет ли вам сборка под старую версию glibc, допишите в вопрос: как делать *кросскомпиляцию* под разные glibc. Может [это](http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/ru/clfs/CLFS-BOOK-mips64.html) поможет.

Comment: Если программа не большая, то может быть ф-ция `syscall()` поможет вам избежать подключение glibc вообще, но я не помню из какой онa библиотеки.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, Вы правы, я написал вопрос криво. Проблема именно при запуске. Попробую сделать то, что Вы советуете. Жаль только, что придётся идти на уступки. Всё же я надеялся на возможность обхода этой ошибки иным способом. И спасибо за ссылку, почитаю.

Comment: Собирайте в таком же  окружении, в каком оно будет выполняться. Способов несколько, например, поставить у себя окружение и ходить в него через `chroot`, любые виртуальные машины с данным окружением (и компилятором), кросс-компиляция.

Comment: @0andriy да в том и суть, что мне нужно охватить как можно больше систем разного времени выпуска, с разными версиями ПО. В большинство из них я не имею права "залезать", то есть обязан пользоваться тем, что есть в базовой сборке. А программы хочется делать с использованием современных стандартов языка. Я добился того, чтобы программы, собираемые на новой системе, запускались на старых системах (видимо это и есть некий аналог кросс-компиляции). Но вот с Qt возникла эта проблема. Делать виртуальные окружение - значит отказаться от современных стандартов.

Comment: Skype, не к столу будет сказано, работает на многих. Вот я думаю, что вам стоит сосредоточиться на нескольких распространённых, проще поддерживать, да и оставшихся можно по отдельному договору.

Comment: @0andriy Думаю, Вы правы. Qt по всей видимости с некоторой версии стала требовать определённые версии glibc, и с этим ничего не поделать. Подсовывать нужную версию glibc в идеале срабатывает, но, например, на ядре < 2.6 это не прокатит (начиная с glibc2.4 осуществляется использование потоковых функций ядра 2.6). Так что придётся использовать старую версию Qt. Думаю, вопрос можно считать закрытым.